# git strategy for project with 2 branches that should never merge

Tags: git, branch, git-fork

*Note: see the Edit part right away for a better explanation*

I'm new to using **GIT** so I apologize in advance if I don't use the right terminology (still learning).

I'm using *BitBucket* since for now I just want private projects.

I would like to know what would be the best strategy to do the following:

I have a **Phonegap/Cordova** app (so it's mostly HTML+JS) for Android. Now, I want to use that project to create an iOS app. Most of the code will be thee same, but there will be platform specific things that I will need to change in the code to make it work for iOS.

My idea would be to be able to:

1. Make a "branch" (or fork?) of the Android version where I can edit whatever is necessary for iOS. This brach would never merge back into the Android version.
2. Whenever I update the Android version, be able to merge those things into the iOS branch.

That way I can always use the Android version as "master", apply any bug fixes, new features, etc, and then "automatically apply those to the iOS version, while keeping its own platform specific lines of code untouched.

So what I'm not sure is exactly how I need to conceptually set up and use GIT with this project so I can keep those branches separate, since everything I've been looking at when it comes to branches seems to end up by merging those into the master, which is exactly what I don't want to do.

Of course I could do all this manually, but if I can use it to learn GIT it would be a great way, and useful!

Thanks in advance!

**-------> EDIT**

The answers I'm receiving are great ideas, but I think I didn't explain myself very well, so I'll try to use another example. The reason is that I think what I have in mind can be used for many other projects, not just the one I explain above, so I would really like to know if it's possible and how.

This is another example:

Let's think about AOSP (Android Open Source Project) and all the custom ROMs created by hundreds of developers. They all use the same source (AOSP or variations of it), clone it, and add their custom modifications to the OS in their own repository. Then, any time there's an update in the AOSP source, they just need to "update" their clone, but keeping whatever they already implemented on their end.

Following the analogy with my first example, my Android app would be the AOSP source code, and my iOS app would be the clone.

So maybe I should somehow use 2 repositories? Or branches/forks? That's the part that confuses me...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing source control (git) with build configuration (whatever build tools you use). Why not just create two folders, /android and /ios, and put the platform specific stuff in there?

Comment: Well I'm not confusing that, I know how to build both versions without issues. The thing is that those version share most of the code, but not all, so I'm looking for a way to streamline the process of updating both versions in the future when I implement changes in the shared code

Comment: My comment stands. Create folders /src/common, src/ios and src/android. If you want to update the code that affects both versions it's in the common folder, so just edit it. Both versions will be affected simultaneously. Use branching for implementing new features, and when you're happy merge it back into master. Have a read of http://git-scm.com/doc to get a basic understanding.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll check that out. What if the code that's different in the 2 versions can't be moved to separate files? I'm not sure that would be able to happen without re-writing quite a bit of code in the original app (which already exists). I guess that worse comes to worse I could do that, but I was hopping to find a better way

Answer (score 0):

Will the android app and ios app share *any* files?

If not, I'd recommend two separate repositories for each of the projects.

Are there lots of files shared?

If so, use one repository and discrete folders for each project:

```
my-awesome-project/
 |____ docs/
   |____ readme.md
 |____ site/
   |____ index.html
 |____ shared/
   |____ my-app.rb
 |____ ios/
   |____ xcode stuff
 |____ android/
   |____ cordova/phonegap stuff
```